# Javascript setter for value of object

Tags: javascript, setter, getter, defineproperty

I have created a "set" function to which it will trigger during the value change of my object "myObject.user". So when i am changing the value i am getting alert. but when i am updating the value inside the object "myObject.newuser[0].id" the set is not calling. How to change the code such that if any inner value is changed the global set should work. ie for this code i should get two alert.

```js
var myObject = {};
myObject.user;
 
Object.defineProperty(myObject, 'newuser', {
     get: function() { return this.user;},
     set: function(value) { alert('Updated');this.user=value;}
});
 
myObject.newuser = [{"id":"user1"}];
myObject.newuser[0].id="user2";
```

Comment: Well you are changing inner object which of course won't trigger setter. I recommend implement the data structure with setter interface. It would be simpler.

Answer (score 0):

Well you need to change the property `myObject.newuser[0].id` to `myObject.user[0].id` then it will set the new value to existing user's value.

Because you changing the previously added value with new value.

Please refer to [MDN link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/set) for more details on setter.